# Facebook responsive doesn't work

Tags: html, css, facebook

My web site responsive but Facebook mobile application browser responsive problem.

Normal mobile chrome responsive screenshot:

[image: image1]

Facebook mobile application responsive screenshot:

[image: image2]

My meta viewport code;

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Comment: Anybody with information on this subject?

Comment: Are you going to supply us with any CSS?